# Installing Cutter(radare2) on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation

I'm trying to get this Cutter GUI working on windows7, I downloaded whatever I could from github page but I can't get it working normally, I'm probably missing something, tried googling but can't find much on this tool, sorry for asking to spoon-feed but please guide me on this, what exactly I need, prerequisite steps to download etc..

This is what I downloaded and how it looks like [image]

So when I click Cutter.exe it starts loading everything, takes some time but opens up normally,  But I have to go through this process everytime, I'm interested if this is actually how it's supposed to be or If i can do anything to make it another clickable tool without having to go through this details

Comment: You should elaborate more particularly about the exact problem you're facing like an error message or something. Without the details the question is vague.

Comment: Yeah I was overwhelmed by this topic. So when I click Cutter.exe it starts loading everything, takes some time but opens up normally,  [ScreenShot](https://i.imgur.com/gyOVrUV.png) But I have to go through this process everytime, I'm interested if this is actually how it's supposed to be or If i can do anything to make it another clickable tool without having to go through this details

Comment: Why're you running from the zip. Extract the zip to a directory and then run.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the details on what exactly you’re doing and what issues you have. Also, did you look at the Github issues or opened your own?

Comment: So I can't use cutter like any other Software Like Visual studio? Github Page didn't have anything that helped me on this, mostly it was linux/mac solutions

Comment: Okay now it works without loading everything, I extracted from Zip to new folder on my desktop, so thats how it should be I guess

Comment: This is not really an RE issue, running any software from inside a zip file does not quite work since it expects all the files to be next to it. Just extract it somewhere first and then run.